# ¿Cómo recuperar el valor de un campo identity en una variable en C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen día, tengo un problema, necesito recuperar en una variable INT, el valor identity de una insercion en sql . ya investigue que se puede hacer con scope_identity() pero no se como implementarlo en mi código.
el código que estoy usando para mandar a guardar a la base de datos es el siguiente.

```
 public Boolean crearcapacitacion(Capacitaciones_model Modelo)
    {
        Boolean Actualizado = false;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new Conexion().CadenaConexion())
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                string Qry = "Insert into dbo.capacitaciones (Nombre_capacitacion,id_entidad) " +
                             "values ('" + Modelo.Nombre_capacitacion + "'," + Modelo.id_entidad + ")";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Qry, sqlCon))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter LeerDatos = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Actualizado = true;
                }
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message); Actualizado = false;
        }
        return Actualizado;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente se hace con `SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);` para este caso ya no ejecutas el SqlCommand con la función `ExecuteNonQuery()` si no con `ExecuteScalar()` para poder capturar el id. En tu caso quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public Boolean crearcapacitacion(Capacitaciones_model Modelo)
{
    Boolean Actualizado = false;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new Conexion().CadenaConexion())
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string Qry = "Insert into dbo.capacitaciones (Nombre_capacitacion,id_entidad) " +
                         "values ('" + Modelo.Nombre_capacitacion + "'," + Modelo.id_entidad + "); SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Qry, sqlCon))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter LeerDatos = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                int id = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                Actualizado = true;
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message); Actualizado = false;
    }
    return Actualizado;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó al 100.